# Examples of numerical solution of stochastic differential equation(SDE)?

Tags: numerical-analysis, stochastic

I want to simulate a nonlinear stochastic differential equation
$$
{\rm d}X_t = f(X_t) {\rm d}t + g(X_t){\rm d}B_t
$$
where $f,g \in C^{\infty}({\mathbb R}^n ,{\mathbb R})$ and $B_t$ is one-dimensional standard brownian motion. How can I do it by MATLAB?

A good simulation file for a similar equation might be helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out this paper by [Des Higham](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0036144500378302) and the [SDETools MATLAB toolbox](https://github.com/horchler/SDETools).

Comment: @Mohammad Khosravi: I was just in the process of typing out my own answer - *I'm the author of SDETools* so I can't say much more. From your notation, I assume that you have an [Itô SDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itō_calculus). First, learn about the very simple [Euler-Maruyama method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Maruyama_method). The Higham paper is a gentle intro, and then if you'e at all familiar with Matlab's ODE suite (e.g., `ode45`) you should find SDETools easy to use.

Comment: @Mohammad : the Des Higham paper cited by Juan is excellent.  You can probably find it for free if you do a little Googling (I did).  Warning: there may be a link to some Matlab files that is out-of-date.  The files are now at http://personal.strath.ac.uk/d.j.higham/algfiles.html .  Second warning: I am having a lot of trouble getting the Octave versions of those files (there is a link to the Octave files at the link I just gave) to work.  I am an Octave/Matlab novice.  I have not tried the Matlab versions yet.

Comment: @Mohammad : I just downloaded and executed the Matlab files at the link I gave above, in Matlab 2013, and they all ran just fine, despite my trouble with the Octave files I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

$$dx_{t}=2x_{t} dt +x_{t} dw_{t}\\x_{0}=1$$

```
% EM Euler-Maruyama method on linear SDE  
%  
% SDE is dX = lambda*X dt + mu*X dW, X(0) = Xzero,  
% where lambda = 2, mu = 1 and Xzero = 1.  
%  
% Discretized Brownian path over [0,1] has dt = 2^(-8).  
% Euler-Maruyama uses timestep R*dt.  

state=randn(100)  
lambda = 2;  
mu = 1;  
Xzero = 1;   % problem parameters  
T = 1;  
N = 2^8;  
dt = 1/N;  
dW = sqrt(dt)*randn(1,N); % Brownian increments  
W = cumsum(dW); % discretized Brownian path  
Xtrue = Xzero*exp((lambda-0.5*mu^2)*([dt:dt:T])+mu*W);  
plot([0:dt:T],[Xzero,Xtrue]), hold on  
R = 4;  
Dt = R*dt;  
L = N/R; % L EM steps of size Dt = R*dt  
Xem = zeros(1,L); % preallocate for efficiency  
Xtemp = Xzero;  
for j = 1:L  
Winc = sum(dW(R*(j-1)+1:R*j));  
Xtemp = Xtemp + Dt*lambda*Xtemp + mu*Xtemp*Winc;  
Xem(j) = Xtemp;  
end  
plot([0:Dt:T],[Xzero,Xem]), hold off
```